# Got undefined properties from subscribe not finished

Tags: angular, subscribe

I'm using Angular and AngularFire to get data from my Firestore Database.

I have two services 'itemsService', 'detailsItemService' which collect and return data from my Firestore collection 'items' and 'detailsItem';

```
// it's the same for detailsItemService
[...]
export class itemsService {

  private items: Observable<Item[]>;

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    private userService: userService
  ) {
      this.items = db.collection<Item>(
        'items',
        ref => ref.where('userID', '==', this.userService.userID)
      )
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(array => {
          return array.map(item => {
            return {
              uid: item.payload.doc.id,
              ...item.payload.doc.data()
            } as Item;
          });
        });
      );
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.applications;
  }
}
```

Then in my controller 'itemsCtrl', I make a subscription to get my 'Items' with uid and I proceed to a forEach to make a subscription 'detailsItem' of each Item with its uid.

```
[...]
export itemsCtrl implements OnInit {

  public items = [];

  constructor(
    private itemsService: itemsService
  ) {
    const items = [];

    this.itemsService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
      items.forEach((item, key) => {
        items[key] = item;

        this.detailsItemService.getDetails(item.uid).subscribe(details => {
          items[key].details = details;
        });
      }
      this.items = items;
    });
  }

  [...]
}
```

But in my view, I got undefined properties when the page starts to load.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <input [(ngModel)]="item.details.name">
</div>
```

Then I get this error :

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` where undefined id 'details'

Thanks for helping :')

Comment: How are you using property "name"?

Comment: I updated my query, check the html please :-)

Comment: getDetails is a async function, so, this.items = items is evaluated first. Try using this.items directly ( this.items[key].details = details;). Also in the template check for details <input *ngIf="item.detail" [(ngModel)]="item.details.name">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.items directly (getDetails is async function and this.items = items will be evaluated before the subscription is completed):

```
this.itemsService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
      items.forEach((item, key) => {
        this.items[key] = item;

        this.detailsItemService.getDetails(item.uid).subscribe(details => {
          this.items[key].details = details;
        });
      }
 });
```

And check if details exists:

```
<input *ngIf="item.details" [(ngModel)]="item.details.name">
```

Comment: Actually I was using this method but [(ngModel)] isn't compatible with value like 'item?.details.name', *ngIf is so simple, I didn't think about it... So thank you so much !

Comment: Do you know how I can implements a [LoadingCtrl](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/loading) with this way ?

Comment: You can call loadingController.create before call getItems, and inside subscription stop the loading indicator. Is that what you ask me?

Comment: Probably, but my context is more complicated than the initial query. I have multiple subscriptions and multiple level of subscriptions into them... So when I put my loading.dismiss() inside the "latest" subscription, the loading box disappears before all data were loaded...

Comment: You can call loading.dismiss() with a timeout

Comment: Mmh, i don't really agree with this... Thanks :)